# $variable in style="background-image: url:( );"

Tags: php, html, variables, url, background-image

I have a question for using a `variable` as IconPath for setting an `background-image: url()`

```
<div style="background-image: url($iconPath)"></div>
```

I have no idea how I can  set the url for the background-image with a variable?

I tried with `""`, `''`, `\"`

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: 4 identical answers and counting, who will get the accepted answer?

Comment: all answers are correct, but I can only give one accepted answer isn´t it?
I´m new here, so what can I do?

Comment: see here [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is a server side language, so if you want anything to be *visible* to DOM (i.e to your HTML), you will have to *print* it to DOM.This is achieved through `echo`

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $iconPath ?>')"></div>
```

Any variable value if needed to be printed, just `echo` it and it'll be visible to DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can `echo` the PHP variables to get its value in HTML. So try like this

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $iconPath;?>')"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $iconPath; ?>)"></div>
```

Or if it is supported (short tags)

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?= $iconPath; ?>)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must echo the variable with PHP. Try like this:

```
<?php
 $iconPath = "/yourPath/image.jpg";
?>

<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $iconPath; ?> )"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if Your Server Side Language is PHP, u can use the below:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $iconPath?>')"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your background picture is 'picture.jpg', the php code you need to type:

```
echo "<div style='background-image:url(&#039;picture.jpg&#039;)'">;
```

Comment: best answer for my case